# Compare byte[] in memory with byte[] from File.ReadAllBytes(), match possible?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, io

I'm writing some unit tests against an API that, basically, takes some populated objects and outputs a `byte[]` which can then be output as an Excel file (that's what the application does with it, but may be irrelevant.)

I wanted to write a test to verify that, given some of those populated objects I'm receiving an expected `byte[]` array, so my approach was to use a previously-output Excel file, and load it at test time to compare to what *should* be output by the code. I do this by reading it via `File.ReadAllBytes()` to get a `byte[]` array, and compare that with the `byte[]` array generated within the app.

I understand the issue with binary reproducibility in .NET, but I'm not sure if that applies in this situation. Can anyone provide any insight as to why the byte arrays don't match? My guess is that reading the file from disk presents some differences in the binary data, or perhaps using the `GetString()` method changes the data somehow at runtime.

My code is below:

```
// The data generated by the app
var data = reportGenerator.GenerateReport(timeFrame, date);
// The expected data
var compareData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Deployment\TestData.xls");

// Get string representation of the data for comparison
var dataString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
var compareDataString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(compareData);

// Compare, Fails
Assert.AreEqual(dataString, compareDataString);
```

The data *almost* matches, but it's not quite identical. When looking at the strings in Beyond Compare, they're probably 99.9% identical with a few small differences.

Comment: could it be that the change is in the saving time date that is embedded inside the excel file ?

Comment: If you run GenerateReport two times in a row, do you get the same output?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If I run `GenerateReport` twice, the output is verbatim the same (diffed debugger data in Beyond Compare). Likewise if I use `File.WriteAllBytes()` to the data twice in a row, separated by a `Thread.Sleep(5000)`, the binary data of the Excel files is verbatim the same.

Comment: Actually, it appears to be working now. My guess is that I imported the file into VS using the "Add -> Existing File" which may have modified the file by creating a copy (and thus the creation date). I just tested by moving the file into the application instead of doing that, and it seems to have identical GetString() data now.

Comment: Is it generating a binary file or is it actually producing a ASCII file like a Comma Seprated file? If it is binary `ASCII.GetString(` will not produce reliable results and should not be used. The first `'\0'` it encounters it will stop reading the binary data. At minimum it needs to be switched to `Convert.ToBase64String(`.

Comment: Side note - post talks about comparing byte arrays, but code shows string comparison... Not sure which one you are looking for/have trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

When working with collections instead of using `Assert` use the class [`CollectionAssert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx) in the same namespace.

You likely want [`CollectionAssert.AreEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243763.aspx)

> Two collections are equal if they have the same elements in the same order and quantity. Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the same object.

```
// The data generated by the app
var data = reportGenerator.GenerateReport(timeFrame, date);
// The expected data
var compareData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Deployment\TestData.xls");

// expected data comes first in a Assert method.
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(compareData, data);
```

As for why `GetString` did not work, it is likely your data was not valid `ASCII` text, passing arbitrary binary data in to `GetString` does not work, the correct way to convert non string binary data to a string format is to Base64 encode it using [`Convert.ToBase64String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// The data generated by the app
var data = reportGenerator.GenerateReport(timeFrame, date);
// The expected data
var compareData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Deployment\TestData.xls");

// Get string representation of the data for comparison
var dataString = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
var compareDataString = Convert.ToBase64String(compareData);

Assert.AreEqual(dataString, compareDataString);
```

If neither of these two methods work then your `GenerateReport` method is not generating the same file every time, perhaps there is some kind of time-stamp or serial number in the file, you will need to parse the file and compare the parsed version if that is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

An Excel spreadsheet contains metadata such as relevant dates and times, the user who created the sheet, the file location, etc. So it doesn't seem like you would ever get a 100% match when comparing raw bytes from file to file.

This is a bit more involved, but you will need to query the data out of each spreadsheet, and compare them in your assertions. There are Office extensions that will allow you to work with spreadsheet data, for example. There is also a Jet driver you can use with an OleDbConnection. I've used it often when feeding lots of cases into my unit tests. An example can be found in this CodeProject article:

[Link to Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/567155/Work-with-MS-Excel-and-ADO-NET)